# convert php to python base64

Tags: python, php, python-3.x, python-3.7

i have this code below:

```
$url = 'https://website.com';

$cookie = 'Cookie: somecookies';

    $postData = 'somedata=6970001596407188738';
    
    
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://ppi.com/api/req?apikey=23575e11111111111111129912");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "postdata=" . base64_encode($postData) . "&cookie=" . $cookie. "&url=" . base64_encode($url));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    $sonuc = json_decode($result, true);
    
    if($sonuc["status"] == "ok") {
```

its a post request obvisouly, but am stick with this part:

```
import base64
print(base64.b64encode(bytes('your string', 'utf-8')))
```

its keep giving me b'eW91ciBzdHJpbmc=' (b) value, how to remove it in python.

I wish somebody can help me convert this code. to python with the request.

Thank you,
regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decode your bytes like this:

```
import base64
print(base64.b64encode(bytes('your string', 'utf-8')).decode('utf-8'))
# eW91ciBzdHJpbmc=
```